# Java - (JSON) What is this called?

Tags: java, json

Guide I'm working with: http://crunchify.com/how-to-write-json-object-to-file-in-java/

I've currently created an application which downloads a big JSON file and parses the data which list items into it, but unfortunately all items are named as it's ID so basically it means that I have to fetch all of the item ID's from separate files, because their JSON doesn't support querying a many items once i.e "item=1983,1093,984,2847" so I have do it for EVERY item individually.

That means I have to make many query connections to remote service in order to find names of up to 35,000 items which isn't very good choice since my query limit will reach to maximum in a seconds.

I want to create a custom JSON file that the item ids and names are fetched into it so it won't use anyone's bandwidth in order to gain item name.

So I'm thinking about 2D array, it's like [int][int] so what is this called for and how do I make my Java JSON (json-simple-1.1.1) understand that the item id will be the (object?) and rest info that relates to that id will be (key?)

```
{
    "1094" // Item ID
    {
        "name": "item name",
        "info": "item info"
    }
}
```

In PHP there was something similar like this:

```
foreach($whatever as $something => $key) {

}
```

Item ID must be the identifier that I can parse rest of the details from it.

Edit: So "item id" should be JSONArray which is placed to object so I can add "keys" to it? I'm not sure about the terms.

Comment: Checkout hashmaps https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: I think that performance-wise you'd better save the 35000 entries as 35000 files rather than a huge file of 35000 entries.

Comment: @Aaron I don't think that's a good idea. Many small files can really mess with performance.

Comment: @Aaron I was thinking same, but then I thought how long it will extract the application when it's shared for friends.

Comment: To share them, just zip the directory they're in.

Comment: @Aaron should I make some extractor or is that possible to read files directly from zip file?

Comment: If 35000 entries in a file is huge in your opinion, then you're playing with pennies. 35000 separate files on the other hand is just ridiculous. Now what's the actual problem? Creating the JSON file? You might want to look at scrappedcola's link and creating a class with the name/info attributes.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm more afraid of holding the 35k entries in memory as a result of manipulating the whole array when only a few entries might be needed. Plus we don't know the size of the entries. And I'm not convinced 35k files is the problem you and Journeycorner depict it to be, would you have any source on that?

Comment: @WeirdE. Reading from the zip file is possible but wouldn't be a good idea (performance cost, code complexity). I would either ask the user to unzip the archive as part of an installation procedure, or provide an "installation script" that does it for them, or add the directory to the source path so that building the application into a jar would pack them too.

Comment: @Aaron 35K entries in memory is only an issue if you're working on a restricted platform or you've gone back in time 15 years. The entries seem to be depicted in the post, having `name` and `info` attributes. 35K files isn't a *problem* for any modern filesystem, but there are no advantages. Of course a database would be optimal, but I guess he wants to pass the data around to his friends.

Comment: Wondering how do I add the values like this: the item id is one object that contains keys name, description etc instead of this "Compnay: eBay","Compnay: Paypal","Compnay: Google"]

Comment: { "1245": { "name": "name" } } instead. ID must be something I can use to identify the name and description, but I have no clue how to generate JSON since tutorial makes company listing different way.